# JBPM transition path not found

Tags: java, jbpm

I am using JBPM version 3.2 and i have recently come across an issue. I have defined a transition path in decision handler and because of spelling mistake decision handler outcome is not matching with any of the transition path values. I got an exception but exception is not saying that outcome is not matching with any transition path, its just a generic exception saying 
"JBWEB000043 not able to create session". My Question is any alternative to find out whether result transition is present in process definition or can throw a specific exception which says transition path is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is very very old version, I mean 10 year-old. If I were you I would try the newest version, it should be 7.7.0.Final or use one of the latest snapshots. I really encourage you to try it. Should you have any questions, please ask it here or on mailing list jbpm-usage@googlegroups.com or jbpm-setup@googlegroups.com.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is an old application I am trying to help in few enhancements so just wanted to know if there is any possibility.